# Unable to initialize class with my list

Tags: java

I'm not able to get rid of this NullPointerException in the following class.  My controller is extending this class and the problem goes away when I comment out the constructor below... what am I doing wrong?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentController' defined in file [C:\Users\bkuhl\JavaProjects\cmt\cmt\target\cmt\WEB-INF\classes\com\site\cmt\web\ContentController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.fettergroup.cmt.web.ContentController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

---

```
public class Controller {
    private List<String> cssFiles;
    private List<String> jsFiles;

    public Controller () {
        this.addCss("global.css");
        this.addJs("global.js");
    }

    public ModelAndView render (ModelAndView model) {

        //add Js & Css files
        model.addObject("cssFiles", this.cssFiles);
        model.addObject("jsFiles", this.jsFiles);

        return model;
    }

    /*
     * Add a css file to the page
     */
    public final void addCss (String cssPath) {
        cssFiles.add(this.cssFiles.size(), cssPath);
    }

    /*
     * Add a javascript file to the page
     */
    public final void addJs (String jsPath) {
        jsFiles.add(this.jsFiles.size(), jsPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cssFiles` and `jsFiles` were never explicitly initialized and are thus null. You should initialize them with a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`.

```
private List<String> cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When you declare a field (class variable) and don't assign it, the value defaults null (for references), 0 (for numbers) or false (boolean).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Controller () {
    this.cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.addCss("global.css");
    this.addJs("global.js");
}
```

and why do you do this :

```
public final void addCss (String cssPath) {
    cssFiles.add(this.cssFiles.size(), cssPath);
}

public final void addJs (String jsPath) {
    jsFiles.add(this.jsFiles.size(), jsPath);
}
```

No need for the first argument really...